# How to put partial in seperate dictionary in Jbuilder Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I have a a json.jbuilder that has `json.template render partial: "partials/#{notification.action}", locals: {notification: notification}`. I want this partial to have a dictionary for it. Instead it returns `"template": "{\"user_id\":\"1\"}"`. How can I make it show a dictionary instead of a string.

Comment: try: `JSON.parse("template": "{\"user_id\":\"1\"}")`

Comment: By *dictionary* i'm assuming you mean an *object* which is the key/value data type in JSON.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean by dictionary. I am trying to get my API to send an object and not parse from my server.

Comment: This looks like a typical double encoding issue. But we can't really help you with debugging without a [Minimal, Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).